# Classifying people's future hopes in a test by using Python?

Tags: python, csv, classification, text-classification

I have a csv file which includes people's hopes about an educational program. So I want to classify people and match them to see whose are having some similar dreams. I am using python TFID for this. What kind of technologies or repositories do you suggest me?
[pieceof a part of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfO78.png)

Comment: this is an open ended question and subject to opinion. Please follow this guide:   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You shouldn't share some of the students' data here or anywhere, unless they consent to make it public. About your question: it's not really a good idea imho, but if anything you can try topic modelling  methods.